# Google Spreadsheet: script to change background color active row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script can you change the background color of the active row when the cursor is in any cell, and reset the background color when I move the cursor to another row?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible for Google Apps script to interact with the browser, thus it has no way of knowing where your cursor is.

What IS possible in Scripts with Sheets is to get the '[Active Cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell())' (or '[Active Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveRange())') of the cursor, but that actually involves the person *selecting* the cell. It won't detect mouse-over.